# Python PIL library convert()

Tags: python, methods, python-imaging-library

I need help to understand how the method Image.convert('RGB') works. I have an image whose each pixel has a value from 0 to 5000. I want to understand in which way the values change after the conversion.
Can anyone explain or suggest some links to understand better?

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: have you look at [the source](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/Image.html#Image.convert) or [the documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert)?

Comment: Do you mean you currently have a single channel (greyscale)  image? What do you hope to achieve by making it RGB (3-channel)?